# Deploy Birt on Google Appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, report, birt

I am not able to deploy the Birt viewer (Web Viewer Example) on GAE. I have followed the instructions provided in "http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/deploy/viewerSetup.php", however the GAE can not find the libraries that i am placing in "WEB-INF/lib". Has anybody deployed Birt on GAE, if it is not feasible what are alternative solutions?

Comment: Are you downloading the pojo runtime or the osgi runtime?

Comment: I have downloaded the Latest BIRT Runtime Release Build: 4.3.1 which i guess is Pojo runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The BIRT viewer is just an example project to show off the implementation of the BIRT runtime, best on localhost for dev time. GAE is supposedly using Jetty for it's servlets so tomcat is not needed which the link you provide suggests.

The viewer is super easy to deploy since you just put it on your servlet engine and voila. Should be even easier if it is packaged as a WAR. You would just need to deploy a war file to GAE, [here is a link to a tutorial on that](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/deploy-flex-jar). From my experiences with the viewer example, I'm pretty sure it is possible, not so intuitive nor easy.

For a lot more versatility than the example viewer, try this tutorial made by some very smart people, [Spring and BIRT Tutorial](https://spring.io/blog/2012/01/30/spring-framework-birt). I have used this to make my own engine for a work project once. This way you could integrate BIRT directly into an existing [GAE Spring project](https://medium.com/google-cloud/getting-started-with-google-app-engine-and-spring-boot-in-5-steps-2d0f8165c89), taken your using Spring.

If you read the Docs thoroughly, you will realize you can just add BIRT as a dependency to any Java project. Then you would simply need one endpoint which can be used to request a report.

Ultimately GAE is just an environment and shouldn't really hold you back from running BIRT.